# Filter formula need to ignore blank values

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U5GM2l7RjUimXpXWwRgwAV5yrXTj7-NIcueQn9g4GNU/edit?usp=sharing

In this document i need to return all column data with all rows data present, it should not return rows either a position is empty or name is empty

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late to answer your question. To delete row where either position or name is empty:

**1.** Select your data in the sheet (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>)

[image]

**2.** Press `F5`. This will open ***Go To Dialog Box***. Then click `Special...` button.

[image]

**3.** In ***Go To Special Dialog Box*** select `Blanks` radio button and click `OK`

[image]

This will select all the blank cells in your data.

**4.** Now ***Right Click*** on any of the selected empty cell and click `Delete`.

**5.** Select `Entire Row` in ***Delete Dialog Box*** and click `OK`

[image]

This will give you your desired result.

**Note:** Take backup of your data before performing above steps.

Comment: @rajup - did this help?